# ConTeXt : Framed blanks

Tags: context, framed

I am trying to insert a blank in a frame in ConTeXt ; below are the options I tried to use :

```
\defineframedtext[experiment]
                 [frame=on,
                   rulethickness=1pt,
                   offset=0pt,
                   width=fit,
                   height=broad,
                   strut=no,
                   location=middle]

\starttext
\startexperiment
  Plop \\
  \blank[3cm]
\stopexperiment
\stoptext
```

However, the frame is always just below the text, and the blank is ignored. How can I achieve this blank space ?

Comment: The `framedtext` environment removes vertical space at the bottom of the box, to retain the space you can use `\startframed` to frame your text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to or simply can't switch to a `framed` environment, just don't zero out `\lastskip` after the blank.

```
\defineframedtext
  [experiment]
  [
    frame=on,
    rulethickness=1pt,
    offset=0pt,
    width=fit,
    height=broad,
    strut=no,
    location=middle,
  ]

\starttexdefinition zerolastskip
  \ifvmode
    \scratchdimen=\prevdepth
    \hrule height \zeropoint
    \prevdepth=\scratchdimen
  \fi
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext

\startexperiment
  Plop \\
  \blank[3cm]\zerolastskip
\stopexperiment
\stoptext
```

---

You can add this to every `experiment` by introducing extra wrapping.

```
\defineframedtext
  [doexperiment]
  [
    frame=on,
    rulethickness=1pt,
    offset=0pt,
    width=fit,
    height=broad,
    strut=no,
    location=middle,
  ]

\definestartstop
  [experiment]
  [
    before={\startdoexperiment},
    after={\zerolastskip\stopdoexperiment},
  ]

\starttexdefinition zerolastskip
  \ifvmode
    \scratchdimen=\prevdepth
    \hrule height \zeropoint
    \prevdepth=\scratchdimen
  \fi
\stoptexdefinition

\starttext
\startexperiment
  Plop \\
  \blank[3cm]
\stopexperiment
\stoptext
```

Comment: A alternative to `\blank` which works in a `framedtext` environment without being removed is `\godown[<NUMBER>]` which insert a given number of empty lines.

Comment: Be aware that `\dontleavehmode` adds a extra line to the frame and you end up with `3cm + 1 line` of vertical space.

Comment: This is a good solution for me. Could someone explain me when I can know if I need \dontleavehmode ? It's the second time I use it to solve a problem (thanks to people here), and it seems like a magical thing to me right now...

Comment: @A.Licari Well, I looked in `pack-rul.mkiv` where `\start...\stopframedtext` is defined and found that `\stopframedtext` executes `\removelastskip`.  That means that one has to somehow clear `\lastskip` and because this is a read only register one has to insert something in vertical mode.  I also revised my answer according to Metafox' comment.

Comment: Well, from what I see after two months, it seems difficult to program my own environment with ConTeXt if I don't read and understand the source code - which is not the aim of a macro package above Plain TeX, if I understand well. I must say that there is a clear lack of documentation / tutorial in my opinion, but this is another debate.

Comment: @HenriMenke You don't need your `\zerolastskip` command because `\vskip\zeropoint` after `\blank[3cm]` does also work.

Comment: @A.Licari: I would appreciate if you can elaborate, either here or somewhere else, what difficulties you had with ConTeXt as a beginner. I occasionally write short articles in TUGboat targeted at begibners, but it is always difficult to guess what difficulties beginners face because I am no longer a beginner.

Comment: @Aditya I didn't know about TUGboat, so maybe I could start reading your articles and tell you afterwards. For instance, I had a really hard time to understand how to customize section titles or make customized boxed environments for maths... The quickly-stated impression that I have is that ConTeXt is made to use the same arguments and structure everywhere, so it is not necessary to explain it everywhere, so it is not explained anywhere, or only in a specified case you cannot guess. I'd have to think it better. Do you want me to open a new topic ?

Comment: @A.Licari: My articles are linked [here](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/User:Adityam#TUGBoat). I can try to write something on how to customize section heads. What exactly do you mean by "boxed environments for maths". Please start a new topic and I will try to answer.

Comment: @Aditya you may admit that your personal page is not the easy thing to find on contextgarden.net. The boxed "environment for math" is settled with `definemathframed`, but it took me hours to find the existence of this command...

Comment: @A.Licari, most of the articles have been merged in the wiki. That is why I don't link them prominently.

Comment: I understood it in the meantime. Now I understand that most "basic thing" articles on the wiki are from you. What I think is lacking is not the very beginner stuff you provide, but something to learn how to efficiently exploit the manual, so to speak. I will think about starting a subject on the question of the doc, let me a few days to organize it properly. Do I start it like a classical question on the forum or is there a better format/way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

ConTeXt removes a vertical skip at the end of a `framedtext` environment.

[image: Missing skip at the end of framedtext]

There are two ways to get around this, the first way is to add a extra skip with a value of 0pt.

```
\starttext

\startframedtext
Plop
\blank[3cm]
\blank[0pt]
\stopframedtext

\stoptext
```

[image: Extra skip at the end of framedtext]

The second way is to set a penalty after the skip which prevents ConTeXt from removing the skip, this can be done with the `samepage` keyword for the `\blank` command.

```
\starttext

\startframedtext
Plop
\blank[3cm,samepage]
\stopframedtext

\stoptext
```

[image: Extra penalty at the end of framedtext]

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but it seems to me that the @Henri Menke's solution is more usable to a user-defined environment than yours, which is more of a general way to prevent a blank skip in an environment, am I right ?

Comment: @A.Licari Creating another environment to use `framedtext` at the cost of losing `\startframedtext`’s optional argument and defining a command which prevents ConTeXt from removing the skip at the end of the environment isn’t more usable than adding `samepage` to `\blank`.